# ERROR COPY import data from a csv file into a table in my Postgres DB

Tags: postgresql, csv

I am trying to import data from a csv file into a table in my DB, but keep getting an error.

SQL QUERY

```
BEGIN;
Copy csv_geometry_tamplate(facility_gis_number,facility_geometry)
from '/home/developer/tmp/facility_Polygon_testing.csv'
DELIMITER ','
CSV HEADER;
COMMIT;
{code}

ERROR:  could not open file "/home/developer/tmp/facility_Polygon_testing.csv" for reading: Permission denied
HINT:  COPY FROM instructs the PostgreSQL server process to read a file. You may want a client-side facility such as psql's \copy.
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the user access DB for location `/home/developer/tmp/` did not have access permission.

I moved the file to `/tmp/facility_Polygon_testing.csv`, then changed permissions with `chmod 777`. This seem to have solved the issue.